# How to autogenerate color vector from a numeric vector

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a numeric vector as such,

```
> z <- c("cat","cat","dog","dolphin","cat")
> z <- as.numeric( as.factor(z))
> z
[1] 1 1 2 3 1
```

from this, how do I autogenerate some color pallette? 
for example, `c("red","red", "blue", "green", "red")` or whatever color pallete is available.

I tried using `rainbow(length(z))` but that did not work.

Comment: You can use `rainbow(length(unique(z)))[z]`, which creates a vector of unique colors based on the factor levels, and then gets color values using the z indices.

Comment: You could also use the RColorBrewer package and make different colors by  `zcolor <- brewer.pal(length(z),"Set2")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that what you are intending is that if the values in z are the same, then the colors are the same. What you want is:

```
z <- c("cat","cat","dog","dolphin","cat")
rainbow(length(unique(z)))[as.numeric( as.factor(z))]
[1] "#FF0000FF" "#FF0000FF" "#00FF00FF" "#0000FFFF" "#FF0000FF"
```

This generates a different color for each distinct value of z, but when the values are equal, they get the same color.

Comment: Nice one. Because factors are integers, you can shorten a bit as follows: `z <- factor(z); rainbow(length(levels(z)))[z]`

Comment: @G5W thanks it worked perfectly and you phrased better.